# Edit text in the blocks for Luma Theme

Tags: blocks, magento-2.1.3

How do I edit the text in the various blocks in the Luma Theme for Magento 2. 
Eg the in the top picture there is a text "New Luma Yoga..." 
Where is this text generated and where do I edit it ?

Answer (score 1):

This content comes from the static blocks in your site's admin. Go to `Content-> Blocks-> Home Page Block` and inside the content area at the bottom you will find the text you want to edit and the code that is calling in the images ect.....

I always disable the wysiwyg editor, as i think it makes editing harder then just editing the plan text, but just a personal preference.

Just a quick note, these blocks are linked to the theme that you have running, so if you were to change to the Blank theme or a third party theme, these blocks would have to be recreated and assigned to that new theme.